# How do I reapply the css grid layout after deleting an element with js?

Tags: javascript, css

I am currently creating a Video Chat application. I am using css grid layout for the videos. These are my relevant html, css and js extracts.

html

```
<div id="videos">
<div class="video-box">
<video id="localVideo" muted autoplay playsinline></video>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
div#videos {
    display: grid;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 4px;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
```

js

```
if (new_peer_added_to_call) {
  document.getElementById('videos').appendChild(new_peer_node);
}
if (peer.disconnected) {
  document.getElementById(peer.id).remove();
}
```

When I add a peer to the call, a new column is created and everything works fine. This also works fine as I keep adding peers to the call. The grid layout stays intact. However, the moment I remove peers when they disconnect, the grid doesn't readjust and instead leaves spaces at the places the video elements were present before. Is there a way for it to update. I would prefer using the css grid layout but I can adapt if I dont have a choice.

**UPDATE:**
I realized the stupidity in my code. Instead of removing the div element video-box for every peer added, I was removing only the video elements inside it.

Comment: Please can you show some sample HTML where the peers have been added. Also, are you sure you are removing the outermost element of the peer, and not maybe an element inside - have you checked a peer has completely been removed with your browser devtools?

Comment: Something like this would help! https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/L8kt1546/  : )

Comment: I updated that example. It seems like it works! So, maybe you are removing the children of the elements that grid is controlling.

Comment: could you share how our html looks after the JS runs so we can see how which element is child? it seems you may be appending `new_peer_node` node but removing an element with id of `peer.id` that may be a child.